# css pos system layout with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I do want to develop a POS system layout based on this image.

[image]

The entire layout should fit into the display height.

The overflow of the item list should be scrollable.

Right side two boxes should take 50% of the display height and the first box should have the scrolling functionality.

This is what I have done so far. How do I achieve this using CSS?

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color:darkgray;
  margin:0
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color:green;
  height:'100%';

}

.items-list{
  background-color:burlywood;
  flex:3
}

.order-details{
  background-color:coral;
  flex: 1;
}

.display-total{
  background-color:blueviolet
}

.item{
  background-color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items-list">
        <p class="item">item 1</p>
        <p class="item">item 2</p>
        <p class="item">item 3</p>
        <p class="item">item 4</p>
        <p class="item">item 5</p>
        <p class="item">item 6</p>
        <p class="item">item 7</p>
      </div>

      <div class="order-details">
        <div class="cart-items">
          <p class="item">item 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="display-total">Total</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Anyhelp" is not a word, or a sentence, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in assigning `overflow-y: scroll` to the scrollable divs, then ensuring their height is restricted so that they're *forced* to scroll.

Here's an example snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.items-list {
  background-color: burlywood;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.order-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: coral;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.cart-items {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.display-total {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="items-list">
      <p class="item">item 1</p>
      <p class="item">item 2</p>
      <p class="item">item 3</p>
      <p class="item">item 4</p>
      <p class="item">item 5</p>
      <p class="item">item 6</p>
      <p class="item">item 7</p>
    </div>

    <div class="order-details">
      <div class="cart-items">
        <p class="item">item 1</p>
        <p class="item">item 2</p>
        <p class="item">item 3</p>
        <p class="item">item 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="display-total">Total</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you like this? I added `overflow-y: scroll;` for the scrollable,
and I added `height: 50%;` to the `.display-total` and `cart-items` so two boxes will take 50% height.

and it works!

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color:darkgray;
  margin:0
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color:green;
  height: 100%;
}

.items-list{
  background-color:burlywood;
  flex:3;
  overflow-y: scroll;  /* I added this */
}

.order-details{
  background-color:coral;
  flex: 1;
}

.display-total{
  background-color:blueviolet;
  height: 50%; /* I added this */
}

.item{
  background-color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;

}
.cart-items {
  overflow-y: scroll;  /* I added this */
  height: 50%;  /* I added this */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items-list">
        <p class="item">item 1</p>
        <p class="item">item 2</p>
        <p class="item">item 3</p>
        <p class="item">item 4</p>
        <p class="item">item 5</p>
        <p class="item">item 6</p>
        <p class="item">item 7</p>
      </div>

      <div class="order-details">
        <div class="cart-items">
          <p class="item">item 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="display-total">Total</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```